# gnome-core packages unmet dependencies Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: kali-linux

I have kali 2.0, I installed 2X nvidia quadro graphics cards as i was trying to install driver to have my extended display working after reboot i got "oh something went wrong " i wasnt able to login so using tty2 i removed gnome and installed lxde i was able to login , now whenever i try to reinstall gnome i get

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-core : Depends: gdm3 (>= 3.14) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: gnome-contacts (>= 3.14) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: gnome-control-center (>= 1:3.14) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: gnome-online-miners (>= 3.14) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: gnome-session (>= 3.14) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: gnome-settings-daemon (>= 3.14) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: gnome-shell (>= 3.14) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: gnome-shell-extensions (>= 3.14) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: nautilus (>= 3.14) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: gnome-sushi (>= 3.12) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried everything i know from updates upgrades clean remove nothing is working I want to reinstall gnome because i cant work with lxde and nvidia drivers or whatever method so i can use my other monitors

Comment: Don't use rolling distros, when you wanna use binary drivers. Binary drivers are always made and tested for stable distros.

Comment: Which drivers should I be installing then |?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kali Linux is a distribution designed for experienced user to use security tools from a virtual machine. It is not designed to offer a comfortable experience for people who are unfamiliar with Linux or as a general-purpose operating system. It is not designed to run directly on hardware. It *can* do all of this but it just isn't the right tool for the job and it's only something that highly experienced users should attempt.

Installing graphics drivers is typically not something you should be doing on Kali. Run a “normal” distribution such as elementary OS, Linux Mint, Ubuntu, etc. on your computer, and run Kali in a virtual machine such as VirtualBox.

Comment: Thank you very much , so that made the gnome problem right ? what if I want to repair gnome or reinstall it ?